# In loopj how to get value to pass in the url of get request

Tags: android, loopj

I got the list of all employees using loopj to get from the rest services using this code.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private ListView employeeList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
getEmployees();
}
    private void getEmployees() {
         List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<Header>();
         headers.add(new BasicHeader("Accept", "application/json"));

         EmployeeRestClient.get(MainActivity.this, "RestExample/employee", 
        headers.toArray(new Header[headers.size()]),null, 
            new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
         @Override
         public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray response) {
         ArrayList<Employee> employeeArray = new ArrayList<Employee>();
         EmployeeAdapter employeeAdapter = new EmployeeAdapter(MainActivity.this, employeeArray);

           for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
            try {
                  employeeAdapter.add(new Employee(response.getJSONObject(i)));
                 } catch (JSONException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }

           employeeList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_employees);
          employeeList.setAdapter(employeeAdapter);
             }
        });
     }
```

I want to get list of employee with, `select * from employees where age = ?`
So in the `getEmployees(Long age)` method how do i get the age value to pass in the url like `RestExample/employee/{age}`

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the `ListView` (`employeeList`), datasource (`employeeArray`) and adapter (`employeeAdapter`) inside `onCreate` rather than doing it in `onSuccess` method.

```
employeeList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_employees);
employeeArray = new ArrayList<Employee>();
employeeAdapter = new EmployeeAdapter(MainActivity.this, employeeArray);
employeeList.setAdapter(employeeAdapter);
```

Your `getEmployees` method,

```
private void getEmployees(Long age) {
    List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<Header>();
    headers.add(new BasicHeader("Accept", "application/json"));

    EmployeeRestClient.get(MainActivity.this, "RestExample/employee/" + age, 
        headers.toArray(new Header[headers.size()]), null, 
        new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray response) {
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                  employeeArray.add(new Employee(response.getJSONObject(i)));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            // notify the adapter that the data has changed
            employeeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         }

    });
}
```

Comment: @neeraj dont i need to pass value to "+age"? for example age = 25, so that it will list all the employees with age 25. in spinner i used onItemSelected to get the age value.

Comment: in onItemSelected i used position the get he value of age of the selected item and passed the value to url to get the desired result. like that here i want to list employee with certain age. in rest service my url is examplerestservice/employee/{age} in age i will give 25 and get the result. like that i have to pass value in client url to consume webservice and fetch the list

Comment: That is exactly what this does.

Comment: How will +age will get for example 25 ? sorry for my ignorance. please tell me

Comment: If age is 25 then, `"RestExample/employee/" + age` will become => `"RestExample/employee/25"`. Isn't this what you need?

Comment: Yes how will i pass 25 to age in place of +age? that is my problem. i have got getEmployees(long age) in oncreate method. here i want to pass age value. from there url will get it.

Comment: Where is your `getEmployee` method? The one shown in your code?

Comment: inside oncreate()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123639/discussion-between-user3785322-and-k-neeraj-lal).